# Cypress (12) component testing is not working for AWS CodeBuild

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, cypress, codebuild

I created this project by using create-react-app (Node v14) with the last version of cypress (12). Also I'm using CodeBuild for CI/CD that in the backgorund is excecuting: `cypress run --component -b chrome`. The pipeline is failing with the following result

```
...
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 12.17.4

[STARTED] Task without title.
[SUCCESS] Task without title.

Opening Cypress...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:43753/devtools/browser/a2c684d6-8a6
[1857:0823/190851.882657:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
Missing baseUrl in compilerOptions. tsconfig-paths will be skipped

tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
================================================================================

  (Run Starting)

  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Cypress:        12.17.4                                                                        │
  │ Browser:        Chrome 114 (headless)                                                          │
  │ Node Version:   v14.21.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)                                                 │
  │ Specs:          15 found (Editor/Comments.cy.tsx, Headline/Headline.cy.tsx... │
 │                                                  │
  │ Searched:       **/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}                                                        │
  │ Params:         Tag: false, Group: false, Parallel: false                                      │
  │ Run URL:        https://cloud.cypress.io/projects/xxx/runs/111                             │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                    
  Running:  Editor/Comments.cy.tsx                                   (1 of 15)
Still waiting to connect to Chrome, retrying in 1 second (attempt 18/62)
Still waiting to connect to Chrome, retrying in 1 second (attempt 19/62)

We detected that the Chromium Renderer process just crashed.

This can happen for a number of different reasons.

If you're running lots of tests on a memory intense application.
  - Try increasing the CPU/memory on the machine you're running on.
  - Try enabling experimentalMemoryManagement in your config file.
  - Try lowering numTestsKeptInMemory in your config file during 'cypress open'.

You can learn more here:

https://on.cypress.io/renderer-process-crashed

  (Results)

  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Tests:        0                                                                                │
  │ Passing:      0                                                                                │
  │ Failing:      1                                                                                │
  │ Pending:      0
```

As a result, the first test is always failing (only the first one). This just happends when I add the `--component` flag when executing cypress. Also, if I change the browser to Electron it fails. So I'm wonder if cypress component testing is working for CodeBuild (aws).
Once the first test fails, cypress continues with the next test that passes normally.

(I tested the `--component` flag in another project and it didn't work.)

I tried to update the node version without success.

Comment: Can you try to set this env var before running cypress `export LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1`. You can try also to disable GPU on Chrome with something like `--disable-gpu`.